# Layouts for VR in Android App

Tags: android, layout, virtual-reality

I have a normal android app which I want to make VR compatible. While searching on web I found out that VrVideoView object is available on android sdk which can be used to render videos in VR.

I was wondering if something similar is available for Layouts as well on android.
If not, one possible way is to keep two layouts one for original and other can be rendered with bitmap of original one but this seems to be very cumbersome and won't scale.

Thanks.